# Carthage: Support for library specific submodules?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, carthage

Per the [docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/README.md), you can specify the use of submodules for all dependencies via the `--use-submodules` flag, as in `carthage update --use-submodules`.

Is this possible though, on a dependency-specific basis?  Imagine for example, that you have a mix of internal libraries (where submodules makes sense) and external, where you don't necessarily want that.

Is it possible to specify this in the Cartfile?

Thanks!